# Разница между типами данных u8, uint8_t, __u8 and __be8

Tags: linux, c, posix

Просматривая сетевой код Linux, я наткнулся на следующие типы данных:

- > u8
- > uint8_t
- > __u8
- > __be8

(также есть типы данных  16, 32 и 64 бит-а)

Может кто-нибудь объяснить,  разницу между этими типами данных и как их лучше всего использовать? Я видел определения этих типов данных, но они не столь явны и понятны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint8_t` объявлен в стандарте `C`  и представляет собой 8-битный целочисленный тип без знака.Если вы работаете в системе, в которой нет 8-битных адресных блоков, они не будут определены *(какая не неожиданность :) )* ; в противном случае это, `typedef` для `unsigned char`.

Все с `__` зарезервировано ядром для использования в реализации. Это означает, что создатели компиляторов и стандартные библиотеки могут использовать эти идентификаторы, не беспокоясь о конфликте имен с пользовательским кодом. Вы можете увидеть это, посмотрев на "внутреннюю" часть реализации стандартной библиотеки.

`u8` не стандартизирован, но почти наверняка означает то же самое что и `uint8_t`. Причина, по которой можно увидеть переменные `u8` заключается в том что `uint8_t` был добавлен в стандарт `C` несколько позже и по этому `u8` можно по сей день увидеть в реализациях.

`__be8` расшифровывается как big-endian(не имеет значения для единичного байта), ака network-byte-order.

Также стоит заметить `__u8`, `uint8_t`, `u8`, идентичны и являют собой 8 бит == 1 байт. Вышесказанное относится к типам `__u16`, `uint16_t`, `u16`, 16 битов  == 2 байта. А также `__u32`, `uint32_t`, `u32`, 32 бита == 4 байта.

*Также думаю стоит упомянуть что порядок следования байтов в архитектуре процессора x86 это "прямой" порядок  ( я бы сказал близок к стековому) то в Линуксе этот принцип работает только в 8 битных машинах.*

Также стоит упомянуть принцы "хорошего тона", как и когда их использовать. Из списка только `uint8_t` определен стандартом `C` в `<stdint.h>`, а `__be8` `__u8` находятся в пространстве имен реализации что в книгах как раз и не описывают, да и многие считают "затрагивать" их плохой идеей (хотя личное мнение что те кто пишут драйвера их "не стесняются").

**Также стоит упомянуть `u_int8_t`.**

в виндовсе используется `uint8_t`, в линуксе `u_int8_t` (также достаточно часто можно встретить в линуксе uint8_t ). Если собираетесь писать платформенное приложение либо "портировать" с [linux-a в windows](https://www.binarytides.com/data-type-u_int8_t-u_int16_t-u_int32_t-on-windows/) то стоит добавить заголовок `<stdint.h>` и заменить все переменные с `u_int8_t` на `uint8_t`.

Comment: "в противном случае это, `typedef` для `unsigned char`" - это совсем не гарантируется.

Comment: "`__u8`, `uint8_t`, `u8`, по сути идентичны" Что такое "по сути"? Являются одним и тем же типом? Или все таки не являются одним и тем же типом?

Answer (score 2):

Типы `__u8` и `__be8` являются внутренними деталями конкретной реализации. Их "нет" и вопроса об их "использовании" не существует. Откуда он вообще взялся?

Ни спецификация POSIX и ни спецификация C не содержит упоминания типа `u8`. Такого типа тоже "не существует". Если некий абстрактный Вася в своем коде определил свой тип `uPupkin8`, это совсем не означает, что вопрос о том, когда этим типом стоит "пользоваться" имеет смысл.

Использовать можно только стандартный тип `uint8_t`, спецификация которого включена и в POSIX. Вне более детального контекста это все, что тут можно сказать.

Comment: "не содержит упоминания типа u8", однако, в стандарте C имеется префикс u8 для строковых литералов.

Comment: @Croessmah Но типа-то отдельного для них нет.